# Drop first row when index doesn't start at 0

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, keyerror, drop

I want to drop the first row of a dataframe `subset` which is a subset of the main dataframe `main`. The first row of the dataframe has `index = 31`, so when I try dropping the first row I get the following error:

[image]

```
>>> subset.drop(0, axis=1)
KeyError: '[0] not found in axis'
```

I want to perform this drop on multiple dataframes, so I cannot drop index 31 on every dataframe. Is it possible to drop the first row when the index isn't equal to 0?

Answer (score 0):

Simpliest is select all rows without first by position:

```
df = df.iloc[1:]
```

Or with drop is possible select first value, but if duplicated values, then all rows are removed:

```
df = df.drop(df.index[0])
```

Your solution try remove column `0`:

```
subset.drop(0, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df if df.index[0] == 0 else df.iloc[1:]
```